# Quiero modificar la fecha de un txt creado?

Tags: c#

Luego de mover el archivo a otra carpeta
File.Move(archivo, path);

quiero modificar la fecha de creacion a la actual, como podria ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar

[File.SetCreationTime(String, DateTime) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.setcreationtime?view=netframework-4.5)

seria algo como

```
File.SetCreationTime(path, DateTime.Now);
```

despues hay otros metodo que podria interesarte cambiar `SetLastWriteTime()` y `SetLastAccessTime`